# How do I make a code stopping the timer as an item for the player?

Tags: javascript

I'm using Perlenspiel, I'm sure that's important.

I trying to make a function that will allow the player to control the timer(pause and unpause) once they pick up the item as well. But that can wait.

Again, I have been able to get the item to show up at the correct bead, have a sound play when player steps on it. But this time, I want it to give the player the ability to pause the game. I've tried to make a function for it, but everytime I make one, it doesn't recognize it in the PS.keyDown section.

Can anyone help me out?

Pausing timer/Unpausing timer:

```
PS.keyDown = function (key, shift, ctrl, options) {
    "use strict";

if(GAME.running && !GAME.paused){
        movePlayer(key);
        if(key == 112){
            PS.timerStop(sTimerID);
            PS.debug("Game is paused.\n");
            GAME.paused = true;
        }   
    }   
    else if(GAME.running && GAME.paused){
        PS.debugClear();
        PS.debug("Game is paused.\n");
        if(key == 112){
            sTimerID = PS.timerStart(GAME.clock, gameUpdate);
            PS.debug("Game is unpaused.\n");
            GAME.paused = false;
        }   
    }
    else{
        PS.debugClear();
        PS.debug("Press r to restart game!\n");
        if(key == 114){
            GameSetup();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here, Jeremy. That would be very helpful for us answerers! If you forget what it said in the Help Center, just remember it next time. But if you haven't read the Help Center *at all*, read it very carefully and follow everything it says when you ask a question. A lot of new comers don't do that. I hope you are not one of them.

Comment: Well, the link I posted in my original post contains my entire code. I suppose I could post it all in the OP through editing.

Comment: @JeremyRoberts please read this in particular http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia Like that?

Comment: Better than before. But you should make another effort, you should post only the code relevant to your problem, you don't want people to read your entire codebase to help you solve a problem.

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia Ok, I think I only put in code that people would be needing to help me with my problem. Let me know if I need to change anything.

Comment: @JeremyRoberts good job so far but you still have problems (you ask two questions, code not formatted in the question...) Read the link I provided, it contains everything you need to make a good question.

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia Ok, hopefully that's everything needed. It doesn't look like I'm missing anything, if I am, please tell me.

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia Ok, nevermind the first one. I was able to fix it so now I just need the second question help. I'll edit out the information for the first question.